# force infopath field to update

Tags: infopath, calculated-column, refresh, data-refresh

How can you force a number field to be updated?

Once the entry has been changed from i.e  365 to 700 the number doesn't refresh. An example I have 2 lines of information. you can only select one by using a radio button i.e 1 or 2.

If one of the fields in line 1 or 2 changes it is supposed to update another value field with the correct number. however, it stays on the first value entered. without selecting the 2nd option is there a way to refresh the field value?

I have selected the rule "refresh value when recalculated" however this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Its all manual process in infopath 2013 for me too.